# Finding the temporal complexity of an exponential algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, runtime, complexity-theory

Problem: Find best way to cut a rod of length *n*.
Each cut is integer length.
Assume that each length *i* rod has a price *p(i)*.
Given: rod of length *n*, and a list of prices *p*, which provided the price of each possible integer lenght between 0 and *n*.

Find best set of cuts to get maximum price.
Can use any number of cuts, from 0 to *n*−1.
There is no cost for a cut.

Following I present a naive algorithm for this problem.

```
CUT-ROD(p,n)
if(n == 0)
    return 0
q = -infinity
for i = 1 to n
    q = max(q, p[i]+CUT-ROD(p,n-1))
return q
```

How can I prove that this algorithm is exponential? Step-by-step.
I can see that it is exponential. However, I'm not able to proove it.

Comment: Shouldn't the recursive call be `CUT-ROD(p, n - i)`? Otherwise, the total length of the cuts can add up to more than the length of the rod.

Comment: As written, one can prove by induction that `CUT-ROD(p, n)` makes n! total recursive calls (for n>=1).

Comment: OK, Paul. But how can we do that? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Let's translate the code to C++ for clarity:

```
int prices[n];
int cut-rod(int n) {
  if(n == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  q = -1;
  res = cut-rod(n-1);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    q = max(q, prices[i] + res);
  }
  return q;
}
```

Note: We are caching the result `of cut-rod(n-1)` to avoid unnecessarily increasing the complexity of the algorithm. Here, we can see that `cut-rod(n)` calls `cut-rod(n-1)`, which calls `cut-rod(n-2)` and so on until `cut-rod(0)`. For `cut-rod(n)`, we see that the function iterates over the array `n` times. Therefore the time complexity of the algorithm is equal to `O(n + (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3)...1)` = `O(n(n+1)/2)` which is approximately equal to `O((n^2)/2)`.

**EDIT:**
If we are using the exact same algorithm as the one in the question, its time complexity is O(n!) since cut-rod(n) calls cut-rod(n-1) n times. cut-rod(n-1) calls cut-rod(n-2) n-1 times and so on. Therefore the time complexity is equal to O(n*(n-1)*(n-2)...1) = O(n!).

Comment: But, acording to your analysis, the runtime of this algorithm grows quadratically proportional to the input lenght. However, in the book of Cormen, they say that the algorithm is exponential.

Comment: If you simulate the algorithm with n=4, you will see that it performs 16 recursive cals. That is, it is indeed 2^n

Comment: OK. Your algorithm does not perform 16 recursive calls. But the algorithm that I presented in the topic does. And my issues are regarding that algorithm. I would like to prove that it makes 2^n recursive calls. I tried the induction method, however, I was not able to reache the expected results.

Comment: The original algorithm unnecessarily calls cut-rod for every iteration in the for loop.

Comment: Indeed...However, I need to prove that it has exponential complexity. I already now, but I need to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this counts as a step-by-step solution but it can be shown easily by induction/substitution. Just assume T(i)=2^i for all i<n then we show that it holds for n:

[image]